# Date Picker on selecting 1 display another datepicker

Tags: datepicker, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I currently have 2 datepickers.

First is StartDate & other is EndDate

On selecting StartDate after clicking on calender i want EndDate's Datetimepicker to be shown & not show/display earlier dates.

Currently i got this:

```
<script>

jQuery('.input-daterange').datepicker({ startDate:'+1', format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});

$('#StartDate , #EndDate').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});


</script>
```

Comment: Please paste a bit of code that you already have. Also elaborate on technology you are using. It looks like you just need to update properties of you datepicker control.

Comment: currently i got this: <script>

jQuery('.input-daterange').datepicker({ startDate:'now', format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});

$('#StartDate , #EndDate').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});


</script>